# OneNote Graph API Expose author information for individual edits

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

The [OneNote Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/onenote) allows the content of OneNote notebooks to be retreived. The [section](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/section) and [sectionGroup](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/sectiongroup) resources have a **lastModifiedBy** and **lastModifiedDate** which gives us author and timestamp information.

The OneNote application itself (both web and desktop versions) exposes author information about *individual edits* within the HTML content of a page. Given this information is available to OneNote, can it be exposed through the Graph API?

Also, we would appreciate **lastModifiedBy** on the [page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/page) object (it already has **lastModifiedDateTime**).

Answer (score 0):

In theory, both asks you mentioned are possible. Could you create uservoice entries so we can track these asks?

https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis

Comment: I have raised a UserVoice entry https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis/suggestions/19601935-add-createdby-createddatetime-lastmodifiedby-and